# Two classes extend from one base class: Is this multiple inheritance?

Tags: java, exception, multiple-inheritance

In Java, it's not possible to extend two Objects from a class.

But how is it possible that `Java.lang.Error` and `java.lang.Exception` both extend `java.lang.Throwable` ?

```
class Error extends Throwable 
class Exception extends Throwable
```

Comment: As its name describes multiple-inheritance .. A class inherited by multiple classes. .. in simple words A class can have two or more child but their father must be one... in java..

Comment: I think you misunderstood. It is not possible for a class to be derived from two classes. But it is very well possible for two different classes to be derived from the same base class.

Comment: In no language is possible to extend, not even a signle object from a class. Only class can be extended or extend another class. :) Inheritance is clas-class relationship. In your example 2 classes extend the same class. Multiple inheritance is when a single class extends 2 different classes (not supported in Java).

Answer (score 6):

What you're describing isn't an example of multiple inheritance - that's just two classes having the same base class. Multiple Inheritance is any case when a class has more than one base class, and this is the case which Java doesn't support.

Answer (score 5):

```
class A extends Throwable , Exception {
} // Compilation error in java - Multiple Inheritance. i.e, 1 class extending 2 or more classes.

class Erorr extends Throwable 
class Exception extends Throwable // two "independent" classes extending the same class. valid in Java
```

Answer (score 0):

In java one child class can only participates in to one inheritance hierarchy. That means one child class can extends only one parent class.Please click the following URL to see an UML diagram that shows such a scenario.

[inheritance in java](http://i58.tinypic.com/168ebm0.jpg)